Metamask extension page not visible by Playwright
I am trying to automate test with Python and Playwright, opening MetaMask extension page, the page is visible on UI but Playwright is not detecting the page.
I've tried to print the num of pages and. to call the browser_context again, still the page of extension is not visible
def test_connect_to_metamask(browser_context_coti): # Interact with the main page page = access_treasury_coti(browser_context_coti) page.wait_for_load_state('domcontentloaded')
hamburger = page.locator("div.Hamburger_nav-icon__15WvU")
hamburger.click()
connect_btn = page.get_by_text('CONNECT')
connect_btn.click()
page.wait_for_load_state('load')

check_box = page.locator('span.CheckBox_checkmark__w4fqa')
check_box.check()

wrapp = page.locator("div.ConnectType_wrapper__lQiRl")
button_locator = wrapp.locator('button.Button_button-component__zTGW4')
button_locator.click()
time.sleep(2)
#page.goto("")
# Debug: Print all open pages
all_pages = browser_context_coti.pages
print("List of open pages:")
for p in all_pages:
    print(f"Page URL: {p.url}")

# Wait for MetaMask extension page
try:
    meta_mask_page = browser_context_coti.wait_for_event("page", timeout=10000)
    if "chrome-extension" in meta_mask_page.url:
        print(f"MetaMask page detected: {meta_mask_page.url}")
    else:
        raise AssertionError("MetaMask page URL does not match expected pattern!")
except TimeoutError:
    raise AssertionError("MetaMask extension page did not open!")

# Interact with MetaMask
meta_mask_page.bring_to_front()
meta_mask_page.wait_for_load_state('domcontentloaded')

meta_mask_agreement = meta_mask_page.locator("[data-testid='onboarding-terms-checkbox']")

